# C# How to make a value in dropdown list null

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu, popup, kendo-ui

I have a popup edit window with a text field, date field, and Type field that uses a `dropdown list`. In the list I have

```
---Please Select One---
```

as an option, and I was wondering how I could make this a null value that will not edit the field when pressed.

```
<div class="editor-field" style="margin-left:33%">
    @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Type).BindTo(new string[] { "---Please Select     One---", "J&J", "Postal" })
</div>
```

The code above is the only line I use to turn the Type field into a `dropdown list`, and it is in the Shared EditorTemplate under the Views, connected into my main view with:

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Holiday
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear to me what you are trying to do.

One improvement that I can suggest is to use `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem[]` instead of `string[]` as your argument to `BindTo', since this will allow you to specify distinct text and value for the items in the dropdownlist. E.g. then you can use "" as value for your empty item which will then be bound as null by the model binder (i.e. when the form is submitted).

What do you mean with "value that will not edit the field when pressed"? Do you want to prevent the `change` event, or make a value that can not be selected, or what exactly?